# Need help with trigger php/mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I need to make this trigger work using three tables.  Does anyone see a problem?

The 'qty' needs to always show the latest quantity from the adds and pulls.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Upd_Cartons_Qty 
AFTER INSERT ON cartons_added FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE cartons_current SET qty = qty + NEW.add_qty WHERE part_no = NEW.part_no;
END;



TABLE NAME:  cartons_current
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| Column       | Type         | Null  | Key   |
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| part_no      | varchar(20)  | No    | Prim  |
| qty          | int(8)       | No    |       |
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+

TABLE NAME:  cartons-added
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| Column       |  Type        | Null  | Key   |
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| part_no      | varchar(20)  | No    | Prim  |
| add_qty      | int(8)       | No    |       |
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+

TABLE NAME:  cartons_pulled
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| Column       | Type         | Null  | Key   |
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| part_no      | varchar(20)  | No    | Prim  |
| pull_qty     | int(8)       | No    |       |
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You cannot use `;` as a final delimiter for the `end`. You need to set a delimiter before the trigger.
2- A `after insert` trigger should logically have a prefix `ai`, not `upd`.
3- You cannot change values in a `after` trigger in the same table the trigger is for. So if you (might) need to change values in `cartons_added` you need to do that in the `before` trigger.
4- On the other hand, you cannot change values in other tables in a `before` trigger, because these changes might rollback and then you have inconstancy i your tables, so that need to happen in the `after` trigger.
5- You can effect multiple tables in a trigger, just do it like the example.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_Cartons_Qty AFTER INSERT ON cartons_added FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE cartons_current SET qty = qty + NEW.add_qty WHERE part_no = NEW.part_no;
  UPDATE cartons_pulled SET x1 = x1 + NEW.add_qty WHERE part_no = NEW.part_no;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you want to alter some value in the triggers own table, don't use `update`, use code like below instead:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_Cartons_Qty BEFORE INSERT ON cartons_added FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Update cartons_added .... will not work.
  -- Use SET NEW.fieldname instead.
  IF NEW.qty_added = 0 THEN 
    SET NEW.qty_added = 1;
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Do I need to add the trigger for each table or only one time?  where do I place the trigger?

Comment: @Erik, you need to add a trigger to each table. Just run the commands and MySQL will attach the trigger to the table, just like MySQL attaches the table to the DB when you do a `create table`.